# How to Prepare the tree based Array with dynamic using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like below. This is dynamic, $main_arr may have an option to add/delete/editable

```
$main_arr['Day'] = array('Day 1', 'Day 2');
$main_arr['Hall'] = array('Hall 1', 'Hall 2');
$main_arr['Session'] = array('Session 1', 'Session 2');
```

I need to prepare the array with tree structure like Parent Option.

```
{"key":2, "name":"Day 1", "title":"Day 1", "parent":1},
{"key":3, "name":"Hall 1", "title":"Day 1", "parent":2},
{"key":4, "name":"Session 1", "title":"Day 1 | Hall: 1", "parent":3},
{"key":5, "name":"Session 2", "title":"Day 1 | Hall: 1", "parent":3},
{"key":6, "name":"Hall 2", "title":"Day 1", "parent":2},
{"key":7, "name":"Session 1", "title":"Day 1 | Hall: 2", "parent":6},
{"key":8, "name":"Session 2", "title":"Day 1 | Hall: 2", "parent":6},
{"key":9, "name":"Day 2", "title":"Day 2", "parent":1},
{"key":10, "name":"Hall 1", "title":"Day 2", "parent":9},
{"key":11, "name":"Session 1", "title":"Day 2 | Hall: 1", "parent":10},
{"key":12, "name":"Session 2", "title":"Day 2 | Hall: 1", "parent":10},
{"key":13, "name":"Hall 2", "title":"Day 2", "parent":9},
{"key":14, "name":"Session 1", "title":"Day 2 | Hall: 2", "parent":13},
{"key":15, "name":"Session 2", "title":"Day 2 | Hall: 2", "parent":13}
```

My PHP CODE ( Copy From its comment ):

```
<?php

$day = 2;
$hall = 2;
$session = 2;
$id = 1;
$main_parent = 1;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $day; $i++) {

    $id++;
    insert($id, $main_parent, "Day $i");
    $parent_day = $id;
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $hall; $j++) {
        $id++;
        insert($id, $parent_day,
            "Hall $j");
        $parent_hall = $id;
        for ($k = 1; $k <= $session; $k++) {
            $id++;
            insert($id, $parent_hall,
                "Session $k");
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: so what did you try? pu some codes...

Comment: Hi, logic prepared, pls check, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prepare the logic by myself for Prepare Dynamic tree based on dynamic array input.

```
$main_arr[] = array('Day 1', 'Day 2');
//$main_arr[] = array('Location 1', 'Location 2');
$main_arr[] = array('Hall 1', 'Hall 2');
//$main_arr[] = array('Sub Hall 1', 'Sub Hall 2');
$main_arr[] = array('Session 1', 'Session 2');
//$main_arr[] = array('Sub Session 1', 'Sub Session 2');

$main_count = count($main_arr);

$arr = array();
$last_arr = array();
$id = $parent = 1;

for($i = 0; $i < $main_count; $i++) {
    $cur_arr = $main_arr[$i];

    $next_arr = array();
    if($main_arr[$i+1]) {
        $next_arr = $main_arr[$i+1];
    }

$parent = $id;
if($i == 0) {
    foreach($cur_arr as $cur_key => $cur_label) {
        $id++;
        $arr[$id]['title'] = $cur_label;
        $arr[$id]['parent'] = $parent;

        $last_arr[$id] = $title = "$cur_label";
        insert($id, $parent, $title, $subtitle);
    }
}

foreach($last_arr as $last_key => $last_label) {
    foreach($next_arr as $next_key => $next_label) {
        $id++;
        $arr[$id]['title'] = "$last_label - $next_label";
        $arr[$id]['parent'] = $last_key;
        insert($id, $last_key, $next_label, $last_label);

        $next_last_arr[$id] = "$last_label - $next_label";
    }   
}
$last_arr = $next_last_arr;
unset($next_last_arr);
}

function insert($id, $parent, $title, $subtitle) {
      echo '{"key":'.$id.', "name":"'.$title.'", "title":"'.$subtitle.'", "parent":'.$parent.'},<br/>';
}
```

?>

Thanks for your support. Image uploaded for reference.

Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ECGp.png

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<?php

$day = 2;
$hall = 2;
$session = 2;
$id = 1;
$main_parent = 1;

$main_array = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= $day; $i++) {

    $id++;
    $main_array[] = array("key"=>$id, "name"=>"Day " . $i, "title"=>"Day " . $i, "parent"=>1);
    $parent_day = $id;

    for ($j = 1; $j <= $hall; $j++) {
        $id++;
        $main_array[] = array("key"=>$id, "name"=>"Hall " . $j, "title"=>"Day " . $i, "parent"=>$parent_day);
        $parent_hall = $id;
        for ($k = 1; $k <= $session; $k++) {
            $id++;
            $main_array[] = array("key"=>$id, "name"=>"Session " . $k, "title"=>"Day " . $i . " | Hall: " . $j, "parent"=>$parent_hall);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i need the login to form the array as like you mentioned based on $main_arr values, this may have an option to add/delete/editable. need a logic to prepare this tree structure array

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what you need to do. What is the login? What is the input data, and where does it need to go? Perhaps you could post some code?